# gem install fileutils error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg, fileutils

Now I'm trying to open SVG file to get the data from it by Ruby language

using Rails 4.0.2 
first I installed the " nokogiri " by using this command [ `gem install nokogiri` ] because I'm using Windows 7

then when I'm trying to install " fileutils " by using this command [`gem install fileutils` ]

But always I get this error

> Blockquote
>   
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>   checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
>   Invalid drive specification.
>   Unable to get ImageMagick version
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.
>   
>   Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.
>   You may need configuration options.

Why i got this error ??

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to install imagemagick first. You can download it from the official project page:

http://www.imagemagick.org

This should do it for you. Generally I suggest you to not to use Windows to develop. Ruby and Rails arent performing well on Windows and you can totally forget running a rails app on a windows host in production mode.

// you cant install imagemagick using the command `gem install rmagick` because `rmagick` is a wrapper for imagemagick but doesnt include the binary files. You need to install imagemagick first. To do that go to the website I posted => Binary Releases => Windows => Download `ImageMagick-6.8.8-2-Q16-x64-dll.exe` and install it. Then run `bundle install` again.

Also it can be a problem using windows when the `rmagick` gem isnt made for windows operating systems. Again: I strongly suggest you tu use a Linux Operating system for everything that is related to ruby, rails or programming web stuff.

Comment: Dear

when I trying to installing **rmagick** by using the command [ `gem install rmagick` ]


I got this error

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.
  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.
 You may need configuration options.

Comment: Sir
After downloading and installing ImageMagick-6.8.8-2-Q16-x64-dll.exe 
then Run the bundle install
i got this error 

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.